Flutter: Access Provider via Listening to Notification
I am facing an issue with handling notifications. I have set up a notification listener, and it is working as expected. However, I want to capture all incoming notifications for my app and store them using the provider package so that they can be accessed from anywhere within the app.
My approach is to use a Provider to store the notifications. When a notification is received, I want to add it to my Provider. However, I am encountering an error when trying to access the Provider within the _handleNotification() method.
I am not ready to switch to riverpod yet, so I am trying to look for possible solution for this if there is.

If there's a better way to do this, I will really appreciate if you could tell me, since I am still learning flutter.
listenNotification() async {

ImprovedLog.log("Initiate notification");
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

messaging.getToken().then((String? token) {
  assert(token != null);
  ImprovedLog.log('Firebase Messaging Token: $token');
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;


  ImprovedLog.log('Message Title: ${notification?.title}');
  ImprovedLog.log('Message Body: ${notification?.body}');

  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      const AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized &&
      notification != null &&
      Globals.isIOS == false /*&& android != null*/) {
    ImprovedLog.log('Local Message Title: ${notification.title}');
    ImprovedLog.log('Local Message Body: ${notification.body}');

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            icon: initializationSettingsAndroid.defaultIcon,
          ),
        ),
        payload: message.data.toString());
  }
});

RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

if (initialMessage != null) {
  _handleNotification(initialMessage.data);
}

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

  ImprovedLog.log('onMessageOpenedApp $remoteMessage');
  _handleNotification(remoteMessage.data);
});
}

void _handleNotification(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
ImprovedLog.log('_handleNotification $data');

NotificationData notifPayload = NotificationData.fromJson(data);


Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context, listen: false).setRedirect =
    notifPayload;

final account =
    Provider.of<AccountProvider>(context, listen: false).account;

if (account == null) {
  ImprovedLog.log("Go to Login View");
  context.push("/login");
  return;
}

ImprovedLog.log("Go to Notification View");
context.push(notifPayload.endpoint);
}


Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.
